# PHP, Notice: Undefined index: al utilizar los indices de array

Tags: php, array

Saludos a todos amigos desarrolladores.
Busco ayuda para el siguiente problema:
hago una consulta Mysqli de los que obtengo un count as estado que cuenta las asistencias de un grupo
y asistencia que obtiene la característica de la asistencia A, F, P, R (asistencia, falta, permiso, retardo).
creo un array para cada uno y utilizo array_combine para establecer "asisencia" como indice y "estado" como valor.
pero al ejecutar el codigo obtengo, Notice: Undefined index:

notas:
1.- utilizando if(isset) no muestra error pero no puedo realizar if(isset) para cada indice.
2.- no me gustaria utilizar @ para suprimir la notificacion.
3.- al realizar var_dump si me muestra los indices y los valores correctos.

agradezco de antemano cualquier aportación.

```
   $resultado2 = mysqli_query($cone, $sql2); 
    while($valores2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)){
        var_dump($valores2);
     $asis=array($valores2["asistencia"]);
     $valor=array($valores2["estado"]);
     $combinado= array_combine($asis, $valor);
     var_dump($combinado);
     if (isset($combinado["A"])){
     $valor1=array($combinado["A"]);
        foreach($valor1 as $v){
            echo"<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo "$v <br/>";
                echo "</td>";
             echo"</tr>";
                }
        }
    }
```

en la siguiente imagen se aprecia lo obtenido del var_dump() y una idea de lo que me gustaría lograr.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi consulta va encaminada a utilizar también para hacer una tabla

```
$combinado["F"]
$combinado["P"]
$combinado["R"]
```

pero todos me darían el mismo error.

### **ACTUALIZACION DE PREGUNTA 03/02/21**

obtengo los datos de dos tablas "pasalista" y "alumnos" relacionadas por la clave "A_Ncontrol".
lo que pretendo obtener es una tabla con el registro general de asistencias por grupo, donde alumnos.A_grupo otorga los grupos y hago un count para cada pasalista.asistencia (que pueden ser A,F,R,P). en este caso mi problema es lo siguiente.
al hacer "group by grupos" la consulta suma los datos obtenidos en forma horizontal y deja los vacios como null.

```
      select alumnos.A_grupo as grupos,
       case when pasalista.asistencia = 'A' then count(asistencia) end as Asistencias,
       case when pasalista.asistencia = 'F' then count(asistencia) end as Faltas,
       case when pasalista.asistencia = 'P' then count(asistencia) end as Permisos,
       case when pasalista.asistencia = 'R' then count(asistencia) end as Retardos
  from  pasalista inner join alumnos on pasalista.A_Ncontrol=alumnos.A_Ncontrol where pasalista.id_Materia=1 group by grupos order by asistencia;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por otro lado al hacer "group by grupos, asistencia" da todos los resultados pero no agrupados y con muchos null, lo que me gustaria es solo tener tres filas 1a, 2a, 3a y los valores de cada campo alineados en la fila correspondiente.

```
  select alumnos.A_grupo as grupos,
       case when pasalista.asistencia = 'A' then count(asistencia) end as Asistencias,
       case when pasalista.asistencia = 'F' then count(asistencia) end as Faltas,
       case when pasalista.asistencia = 'P' then count(asistencia) end as Permisos,
       case when pasalista.asistencia = 'R' then count(asistencia) end as Retardos
  from  pasalista inner join alumnos on pasalista.A_Ncontrol=alumnos.A_Ncontrol where pasalista.id_Materia=1 group by grupos, asistencia order by grupos;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta es un poco confusa. ¿Dónde ocurre el *Undefined index* exactamente? Además, ¿por qué mareas tanto los datos usando array_combine y otras historias? Las APIs de consulta de BD de PHP te permiten organizar los datos obtenidos por diferentes métodos, los cuales incluyen crear arrays asociativos, o incluso mapear los resultados a objetos, o crear estructuras organizadas como JSON. Quizá si explicas un poco mejor el problema podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarnos la línea exacta donde te salta el "notice"? Marca con un comentario la línea en cuestión.

Comment: Entiendo que le estoy dando muchas vueltas a los datos, pero llevo varios días atorado y no sabia como resolverlo porque directamente de la consulta me arrojaba todos los índices como 0, así que pensé que seria la forma mas fácil de asociar la información para mostrarla cuando sea asistencia, falta, etc. 
directamente el error que arroja es Notice: Undefined index: A in C:\xampp\htdocs\graficas\tabla.php on line 29.
lo que tengo en esa linea es $valor1=array($combinado["A"]);

Comment: no quisiera parecer alguien que espera todas las respuestas sin buscar, la verdad es que he buscado y he leído mucho, si alguno conoce otra forma de hacerlo o pudiera darme algún indicio se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Estoy casi seguro de que el problema que tienes ahora es debido a un mal planteamiento a otro nivel, que sería la consulta SQL en sí misma. ¿Por qué no organizas la consulta de forma **que te traiga ya los datos como los quieres, en vez de traerlos de cualquier manera para luego organizarlos, haciendo una doble manipulación de datos**? No parece un problema tan complicado, pero sin entender el contexto no podremos ayudarte a encontrar el problema o a optar por una solución más óptima. Si es posible, explica qué estructura tiene(n) la(s) tablas, y muestra la consulta SQL que estás ejecutando.

Comment: Creo que no entiendo cómo almacenas la data ni como es la query actual. Cada registro es un empleado? Un día? Un grupo de empleados de una misma área?

Comment: saludos desarrolladores, gracias por su apoyo e interés, he estado explorando lo que dijo A.Cedano, pero han surgido otras dudas, he actualizado mi pregunta original con mi nueva duda he tratado de ser claro y explicito, espero que puedan seguir orientandome.